# Hubot Slack: Removing from #general

Tags: hubot, slack

I'm wondering if anyone has any form of solution for this? I've been googling for some time now and can't seem to find a solution.

Is there a way to either remove Hubot from Slacks default #general channel or have him so he mutes himself and doesn't respond to commands in the channel directly, perhaps instead private messages the person? I want to implement my bot into my organization but I want to avoid situation where he floods general chat by responding to a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to "/kick hubot" command on the #general channel?
It should work like for any other users

Comment: I had no idea I could kick users from general. Worked great, thanks!

Comment: Tried this, it returns: You can't remove this member from *#general*!